# Oscillating boost converter output voltage that has a differential amplifier for load, in DRV8662 piezo actuator driver IC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, oscillation

I am building a circuit to drive a piezo stack in a pulsatile fashion and I am using  the DRV8662 piezo driver from TI to do so. The circuit diagram is shown here (please disregard the several ammeters and voltmeters shown):

[image: Circuit schematic]

The DRV8662 chip has the following internal circuit (block diagram):

[image]
As you can notice, I am imitating the load of the piezo stack of interest through a 380ohm resistor in series with a 1uF capacitor. However, the issue I am facing is concerned with the voltage at VBOOST (PVDD) which in fact serves as a power supply to the amplifier, whose output is supposed to drive the piezo actuator.

The simulation of the circuit was done through TINA, from TI, which gave good results, and for now I am trying to build a small prototype on a Breadboard together with a proper IC adapter, which, I know, is not perfect, but I thought should work for a proof of concept, so to speak, even if imperfectly.

A picture of the breadboard together with an Arduino-nano that drives the EN and Input terminals of the IC is shown here:

[image: Breadboard construction]

The circuit is designed to have around 80V at PVDD once the EN signal is activated and once the Input signal is high the output+/- should give 75V across the piezo stack terminals. However, what I noticed when I probed the breadboard through an oscilloscope, while applying several pulses at the input, was that after the PVDD voltage dips as a result of the current discharge from the boost cap to supply the amplifier, sometimes the PVDD oscillates with a magnitude in the tens of volts in a certain fashion never to settle back until the input pulse turns low again, sometimes it settles then oscillates and vice versa, and in other times it settles around the intended DC value with no problem. In the presence of only the relatively small ripples the voltage is considered "settled". All these scenarios can happen in the same run with different pulses applied immediately after one another, not some seconds or minutes later. This is shown here (note the relation to the input pulse, depicted in orange):

[image]

For a closer look:

[image]

The way I see it, this oscillation is not the result of the rates of charge/discharge dictated by the capability of the boost circuit or the demand of the load, but rather an unstable behavior, perhaps something is disturbing the feedback loop of the boost controller. If we zoom in further, we can see the ripples caused by the boost switching carried over the oscillating signal:

[image]

I hope somebody might have a clearer understanding of why this is happening and how to go about fixing this problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: TI specifies a *maximum* load capacitance of 150nF at your output voltage. The circuit is probably unstable possibly due to the load capacitance.

Comment: That's true if the conditions were the same, the 150nF is the limit with these conditions: (VBST = 80 V, Frequency = 300 Hz, VO,PP = 150 V); however, the frequency I am working with in the first two graphs is 5Hz. This allows me to raise the load capacitance. For example, the circuit can handle 1uF with these conditions: (VBST = 25 V, Frequency = 300 Hz, VO,PP = 40 V). Again, the freq here is 300Hz, so if I lower the freq I should be able to raise the boost voltage.